# catch postgresql command execution error from php file

Tags: php, postgresql-9.1

I m a begineer in php and having some problem as :

I have a **php file** having a function **create_dump()** in which I am dumping my **postgresql database** using **pg_dump** command. 
Now while executing php file from linux terminal it asks for **postgresql password** on terminal.
 I want to add error handling in my php file if user provides wrong password for the database unintentionally.

In other words : 
How to catch **pg_dump** (postgresql command) execution error from my php file ?
Thanks !

Comment: Could you provide the code that runs the command in your PHP script?

Comment: code for command in create_dump function inside php file is : **$command="/usr/bin/pg_dump --a --no-owner --no-acl --attribute-inserts --disable-dollar-quoting --no-tablespaces --host=".$db['hostname']." --user=".$db['username']." --password --port=".$db['port']." ".$db['database']." >".$path['schema_path']."schema-'$latest_update'.sql";          $output = passthru($command);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info you provided I have a workaround for what you want to do. First, instead of piping the output of your dump using the '>' you will need to use the --file=some_file.sql flag instead which does the same job.

Now, it does not appear that the $output from the passthru call will capture the output even if you send stderr to stdout so here's what would work. You would modify the command using the --file= flag and pipe the output of the command (which contains the error) to a log file while making sure to also send stderr to stdout (do 2>&1 after the command) in order to capture the error.

Here's the code:

```
// notice the file= flag and the piping of error to the file
$command=
    "/usr/bin/pg_dump --a --no-owner --no-acl --attribute-inserts ".
    "--disable-dollar-quoting --no-tablespaces ".
    "--file={$path['schema_path']}schema-{$latest_update}.sql ".
    "--host={$db['hostname']} --user={$db['username']} ".
    "--password --port={$db['port']} {$db['database']} > pg_dump_error.log 2>&1"; 

// no output to capture so no need to store it
passthru($command);

// read the file, if empty all's well
$error = file_get_contents('pg_dump_error.log');
if(trim($error) != '')
    exit("PG_DUMP ERRROR:\n-----\n$error\n");
```

Hope this is more or less what you were looking for.